# calculating sum of value using where condition in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am trying to calculate sum(subproducts)/sum(products)

I tried using case statement

```
select round((case when b.in_nt ='y' then (sum(b.amount)) end)/
(sum(b.amount)) ,2) as spec_pi
FROM  products b
group by b.in_nt;
```

I am getting 2 rows instead of 1 row. Null and value.
I need only value to be displayed.

Comment: Post a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select sum(case when b.in_nt ='y' then b.amount end)/(sum(b.amount)) ,2) as spec_pi
    FROM  products b
```